# $f(x)=x^2-a \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ - show propositions

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f(x)=x^2-a \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
$$p \in \mathbb{P}, p \neq 2, p^2 \nmid a$$

The equation $f(x)=0$

- If $p \mid a $, the equation has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Let $p \nmid a$.

- The equation has exactly two solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_p \Leftrightarrow \left( \frac{a}{p}\right)=1$
- It has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p \Leftrightarrow \left( \frac{a}{p}\right)=-1$

Why does it have to hold that $p^2 \nmid a$?

In order to prove the first proposition I thought that since $p \mid a $ and $p^2 \nmid a$ it has to hold that $a=kp, p \nmid k$. Since $p$ is a prime, it will hold that $(p,k)=1$. Thus $a$ cannot be written as a square and so if $p \mid a$, the equation $x^2-a$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Is it right?

The second and the third proposition hold from the definition of the Legendre symbol. Am I right?

**EDIT**: And how could we show that $f(x)=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_2 \iff a \equiv 1 \mod 8$ ?

Answer (score 2):

For the first time, it is an application of [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).

For the second part, it is more or less correct, but you should consider that the Legendre's symbol is defined for integers, and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$: if $(x/y)^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$ then $p$ cannot divide $y$, so there exists a multiplicative inverse $z\neq 0$ such that $p\mid yz-1$. It follows that $(xz)^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$, and now we are talking about integers.

Comment: I see... :) And it has exactly two solutions since its degree is $2$.. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactlt two since $p\nmid a$ ;)

Comment: Nice... And how could we show that $f(x)=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_2 \iff a \equiv 1 \mod 8$ ?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of ways. This is a strange one ahahah
https://leonettipaolo.wordpress.com/xyz/

Comment: Paolo :) Could you tell me also an other way? :/

Comment: Almost every book of number theory treats quadratic reciprocity, quadratic reciprocity and so on. If you want a really quick explanation, check here: http://imomath.com/index.php?options=329&lmm=0 theorem 9.